# How can I open multiple equal documents in a neat way with cmd using evince?

Tags: evince

I couldn't find it on the man page so here we go. I'm opening multiple documents of same type (`.pdf`, `.tex` etc.) on a daily basis. According to [this](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/commandline.html.en), it's possible, however I'm looking for a more neat way/shorter code i.e. insted of `evince file.ext file.ext ...` I'd like something like `evince file.ext*4`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to open 4 times the same file?

Comment: I picked four as an arbitrary #. I'm looking for something general (2, 3, 4, ...).

Comment: Yes, but shall it be the exact same file?

Comment: Oh yes the same file.

Comment: That would be the last part of my answer, though admittedly it is not much neater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to open multiple documents of same type, you just have to match the part that is similar in the files you want to open.

E.g. if you want to open all pdf files in a folder, you would run

```
evince *.pdf
```

if you want to open all pdf files beginning with 2 you would run

```
evince 2*.pdf
```

If, what you meant is opening 4 times the same file, you could run

```
for i in $(seq 4); do  evince file.ext & done
```

[Here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) you can find some more examples on pattern matching.

Comment: trying to use that on `masterpdfeditor4` didn't work only opens first pdf file found...

Comment: @George did you try the pattern matching or the loop? Pattern matching works with okular and should work with all commands that accept more than one file as a command line argument. Unfortunately I am not aware of masterpdfeditor4

Comment: I wrote a for loop for that but `masterpdfeditor4` doesn't seem to be able to handle file names with `spaces`

Comment: @George That is not masterpdfeditor4's fault. My code does not escape spaces and bash uses space as a file delimiter

Comment: @George just put the filename in double quotes "file.ext"

Comment: I did that i my code but still didn't fly

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with a shell function in your profile you could do this:

```
ev() {
  [[ -z "$*" ]] && echo "usage: ev file [files] [#rpt]" ||
  case ${@:$#} in
    *[!0-9]*) evince $*;;
    *) evince `yes ${@:1:$#-1} |head -${@:$#}`;;
  esac
}
```

For example, `ev foo.tex 2` runs `evince foo.tex foo.tex`. If the last argument is not a number, evince is run with the regular arguments.